# FFMPEG gem is not generate correct bitrate value for a video in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ffmpeg, rubygems

I am using FFMPEG gem in rails, and I want to store bitrate value for a video in a table

I put this code in utility library/module

```
movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new(path)
media_detail = {duration: movie.duration, bitrate: movie.bitrate, resolution: movie.resolution}
```

On the show page I am using `number_to_human_size` rails helper method for more understandable representation

```
number_to_human_size(convert_bit_to_byte(file.bitrate))

def convert_bit_to_byte(bitrate_value)
     (bitrate_value.to_i*125)
end
```

So I want an average bitrate value for a video in bytes for `number_to_human_size` method for good representation but I am not getting the average value and FFMPEG gem generates everything as expected but only in bitrate there is some problem.

Comment: What exactly is "some problem"? Please edit your question (and don't just add a comment) to add much more details about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Airst of all FFMPEG gem generates bitrate for a video in bits per second and I am trying to pass b/ps to rails helper method `number_to_human_size` who needs data in bytes per second not in bits per second.

For this I did not change anything from initial point

```
movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new(path)
media_detail = {duration: movie.duration, bitrate: movie.bitrate, resolution: movie.resolution}
```

But from an end point I'll convert my data to bytes like this

```
number_to_human_size(convert_byte(file.bitrate))
def convert_byte(bitrate_value)
     (bitrate_value.to_i/8)
end
```